# How to add a .tar library into my project

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

i use Xcode 4.2 and i need to integrate an external library, obviously, it was taken as compressed file(.tar), so in Xcode, when i add it and try to import its files in my code, they aren't recognized, so the library isn't correctly imported although i see it in my project Groups and Files Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.tar isn't compression, it's an archive. Try unarchiving it and importing the file or files inside the archive.